# Why doesn't input text work in Google Chrome?---negative z-index

Tags: javascript, input, z-index

So here's a bug for you.  Using the following text, the input field **won't change its cursor and gain focus**, in Google Chrome 22.0, so **you can't type in the input box**.  (It works OK in both FireFox and I.E.)  Why does it do this?

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="z-index: -10; position:fixed; top:20; left:20; bottom: 20; right: 20;">
  <form action="">
  <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Will this be changed in future versions of Chrome?  What was the design thinking here?

Comment: html and body do not have height and width attributes. use css on the body.

Comment: good catch--garbage left over from extremely nasty debugging session. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The code is using a negative z-index in the div.  Due to a bug in Chrome, one must have a z-index larger than 0 for the form to allow interaction, even though the elements are displayed.  Presumably this tends to guard against hidden input forms in cross-loaded advertising code, although it's just as easy to hide a form by covering it up or putting it off the page, so this does not seem to be effective.  Since, even if it gets fixed in the future, old browsers may still have this bug, simply **make sure never to use negative z-index numbers** on any code that might run on Chrome.

Comment: Is "to guard against hidden input" a guess or is there some source you can reference? Is this still true if _everything_ is given a negative z-index?

Comment: It is speculation.  However, yes, the code still does not work if all of the divs have negative z-indices and the input is still displayed on top as the least negative.  So looks like a bug, not a feature.

Comment: Is this still relevant today? Any source to support this claim?